# Python script gets killed in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, memory, out-of-memory

I am currently trying to run a long running python script on Ubuntu 12.04. The machine is running on a Digital Ocean droplet. It has no visible memory leaks (top shows constant memory). After running without incident (there are no uncaught exceptions and the used memory does not increase) for about 12 hours, the script gets killed.

The only messages present in syslog relating to the script are

Sep 11 06:35:06 localhost kernel: [13729692.901711] select 19116 (python), adj 0, size 62408, to kill

Sep 11 06:35:06 localhost kernel: [13729692.901713] send sigkill to 19116 (python), adj 0, size 62408

I've encountered similar problems before (with other scripts) in Ubuntu 12.04 but the logs then contained the additional information that the scripts were killed by oom-killer.

Those scripts, as well as this one, occupy a maximum of 30% of available memory.

Since i can't find any problems with the actual code, could this be an OS problem? If so, how do i go about fixing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your process was indeed killed by the oom-killer. The log message “select … to kill“ hints to that.

Probably your script didn’t do anything wrong, but it was selected to be killed because it used the most memory.

You have to provide more free memory, by adding more (virtual) RAM if you can, by moving other services from this machine to a different one, or by trying to optimize memory usage in your script.

See e.g. [Debug out-of-memory with /var/log/messages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128642/debug-out-of-memory-with-var-log-messages) for debugging hints. You could try to spare your script from being killed: [How to set OOM killer adjustments for daemons permanently?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58872/how-to-set-oom-killer-adjustments-for-daemons-permanently) But often killing some process at random may leave the whole machine in an unstable state. In the end you will have to sort out the memory requirements and then make sure enough memory for peak loads is available.